# How to restrict the serialization of extended properties on related entities that extend the same entity?

Tags: symfony, serialization, api-platform.com

I have complications with normalization between entities extending the same entity.

I have some **MyEntity[Type]** entities that extend **MyEntity**.
Some of the **MyEntity[Type]** have relationships with some of them.

Here the MyEntityBob :

```php
    #[ApiResource(
        itemOperations: [
            'get' => [
                'path' => '/myentity_bob/{id}',
                'normalization_context' => ['groups' => ['read:MyEntityBob:item']]
            ]
        ]
    )]
    class MyEntityBob extends MyEntity
    {
        #[Groups(['read:MyEntityBob:item'])]
        private $private_bob_property;

        #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: MyEntityToto::class)
        #[Groups(['read:MyEntityBob:item'])]
        private $myentity_toto;
    }
```

Which is related to the MyEntityToto :

```php
    class MyEntityToto extends MyEntity
    {
        #[Groups(['read:MyEntityToto:item', 'read:MyEntityBob:item'])]
        private $shared_toto_property;

        #[Groups(['read:MyEntityToto:item'])]
        private $private_toto_property;
    }
```

Both of which extend MyEntity :

```php
    #[ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED"), ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name: "type", type: "string"), ORM\DiscriminatorMap(["bob" => "MyEntityBob", "toto" => "MyEntityToto"])]
    abstract class MyEntity
    {   
        #[Groups([
            'read:MyEntityBob:item', 'read:MyEntityToto:item'
        ])]
        private $partial_problematic_property;
    }
```

Now, here's the problem,
When I do the request **/myentity_bob/{id}**, I want to get the following result:

```json
{
    private_bob_property: "no problem here",
    myentity_toto : {
        shared_toto_property: "i'm okay"
    },
    partial_problematic_property: "it's all good"
}
```

But, because of the extends on MyEntityToto with MyEntity, I get this :

```json
{
    private_bob_property: "no problem here",
    myentity_toto : {
        shared_toto_property: "i'm okay",
        partial_problematic_property: "I'M NOT SUPPOSED TO BE HERE!!!"
    },
    partial_problematic_property: "it's all good"
}
```

Edit: In other words, the problem is on the relation with MyEntityToto. I get it extends properties, but I don't want it.

A possible solution would be to modify the serialization group of an entity property programmaticaly, but I don't know if it's possible.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand: If you added a parent property to the group, and apply this group, why do you expect it will not be present in result?

Comment: @IliaYatsenko The problem is on the relation with MyEntityToto.
It also extend MyEntity, so the serialization group is apply on its extends properties.

But this not why I want, like I show it at the end of my post, I don't wan't the "partial_problematic_property" in the relation.

Comment: did you try to remove read:MyEntityToto:item group from partial_problematic_property?

Comment: Why do you think this has something to do with `[relational-database]`?